# AngularJS select seems to need to match on the same object to set the selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have asked a question very recently [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454384/selected-value-for-angular-select-not-be-set-on-page-refresh) about why my angular select is not setting my select using saved answers.

This is my select:

```
        <select ng-model="question.answer" ng-options="opt as opt.Value for opt in question.options" />
```

The answer by pkozlowski.opensource to[this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select)  got me thinking that the value that is being set in the `ng-model` of my select can't be matching any of the values that are being passed as options in the `ng-options` of my select.

I created [this jsfiddle that should highlight the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/8wtE8/). Whenever the answer is changed the answer object is logged to the console. (*Note that for some reason it is being logged twice in jsfiddle, but it's only being logged once when I run the same code locally on my machine*)

You can see that when the button is pressed, the answer logged out is the same object structure as the third option, *but* the picklist is set to a blank option.

*Output logged to console after setting the picklist to the third option:*

```
answer is: picklistTest.js:25
Object {id: 3, Value: "Three"}
```

*Output logged to console after clicking the "setToThirdAnswer" button:*

```
answer is: picklistTest.js:25
Object {id: 3, Value: "Three"}
```

It is the same structure, but not the same object. So I wondered if the object in the model has to be ***exactly*** the same object as one of the options.

[This second jsfiddle shows that that is the case](http://jsfiddle.net/CkLEu/). The button is setting the answer to be a reference to one of the option objects.

So, I'm happy that I have found out why my selects weren't setting the selected value after a page refresh, but now I would really like to know (and this *must* be a very common use case):

If my options are objects and I am setting the whole object to the `ng-model`, how can I use saved json to re-render the form without first doing some processing on the client side?

```
var json = question = {
    options: [
       {
           id: 1,
           Value: "One"
       },
       {
           id: 2,
           Value: "Two"
       },
       {
           id: 3,
           Value: "Three"
       }
   ],
   answer: {
               id: 3,
               Value: "Three"
           }
};
```

because the answer object and the third value of the options array ***aren't the same object***, but you can't represent a reference in json (can you?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-options attribute has a `track by` expression to do just what you're talking about:

```
ng-options="opt as opt.Value for opt in question.options track by opt.id"
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CkLEu/6/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have the same reference. You can do this like so:

```
question.answer = question.options[2]
```

Directly after you create it.

Comment: This is totally wrong in general, what if the order of items changed, hardcoded index is a bad idea!!